# How to retain ubuntu default terminal theme?

Tags: 17.10, themes

I love arc theme but it changes my terminal theme to a white one.
I want the default theme of terminal that comes with fresh install.[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Un-check "Use colours from system theme" as that means you are using the arc theme.
2. Change the green text colour to white
3. Set the background colour to `#300A24`

Everything else should be the same as the default Ambiance colour scheme.